# AndroidStudio 2.1.1 changes made in xml doesn't get updated on run

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-build

I am now using `AndroidSudio 2.1.1` for my android development.

When I make any changes in xml files (layout , color, string, drawable etc) and then run my app, I don't see any changes in my output.

I have to clean or re-build my project to see the changes made in xml files.

**I have already turned off instant-run** still no use.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We have same problem with big project, over 2000 res files in merge folder.

Comment: @RexHunt : it was with AS 2.1.1 , now using 3.5.3 , almost 3 years . Why are u still using old AS ?

Comment: We use same 3.5.3 and we've got same issue. But we found reason. We used different flavors and for each we set srcDir paths. Reason was in main flavor, it shouldn't have srcDir in build.gradle.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to `clean` and `Rebuild` the project.

Then go to `File/InValidate Caches and Restart` and select `Restart`. It should solve your problem.

I've had the same error and I think this happened because of cache memory store value in `Android Studio`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this button :
[image]

Or simlpy do **clean** , **rebuild** .

Comment: I do this in every run of my app . I want to get rid of it.